# How do determine where the slide is made and how can it be set to be performed when a button is clicked?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, slide, buttonclick

I used the code from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon) and I don't know how to determine which part does the slide action. I run it in debug mode and when I slide with the finger from the left-side this is what I get:

```
08-08 13:09:42.125    3161-3161/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4 
08-08 13:09:42.125    3161-3161/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called 
08-08 13:09:42.155    3161-3161/info.androidhive.slidingmenu D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
```

I don't have that classes or methods in my project and I don't know how to handle with this. What **I want is to set the sliding to be performed when a button is pressed** too, not only from finger actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open/close the navigation drawer when a button is pressed, add the following code to the  `onClickListener` for the button:

```
if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); // to close it
else
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); // to open it
```

If your drawer is on the right, use `Gravity.RIGHT`. You can also use the `View` for the drawer as a parameter. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code for LEFT Drawer.

```
 swapDrawerBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          if (!drawer.isOpen(Gravity.LEFT))
              drawer.openDrawer (Gravity.LEFT);
          else
              drawer.closeDrawer (Gravity.LEFT);
     }
 });
```

Is it exactly what you want?

Comment: `Drawer` is instance of DrawerLayout:  `drawer= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);` from [your tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon)

Comment: Other situation if you want open/close with button in ActionBar. It's a little bit more complicated